# Minimize a certain class error in a multi-class random forest model (tidymodels)

Tags: r, random-forest, tidymodels

(Note I don't have a reproducible example yet, but I'm working on it).

I've trained a random forest model using the tidymodel framework. My outcome is a categorial variable with three categories.

Now, when looking at the confusion matrix between the predicted classes and the actual classes, I notice that there's a certain cell, where the class error is particularly high:

Example table:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  predicted_class actual_class_1 actual_class_2 actual_class_3
  <chr>                    <int>          <int>          <int>
1 1                          260             77             20
2 2                          109            460             84
3 3                           52             99            781
```

In particular, I'm worried about/interested in the mismatch for class 1 where the model predicted class 2 (i.e. the N=109 cases, which is 26% of class 1).

Now, my question is: is there a way to setup the random forest model in a way to optimize on a certain class error, trying to reduce the 26% mismatch here?

One naive approach I can imagine is just to use a different probability threshold when assigning classes 1 and 2, but I was hoping there's a more defendable/model-inherent approach.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`ranger::ranger()` has an argument called `class.weights` and `randomForest::randomForest()` has `classwt`. Both are numeric vectors.

These let you prioritize (or deprioritize) specific classes in the tree construction.

You can pass these vector arguments to `set_engine()`. We don't have a tool to optimize them (yet - probably binary outcomes only) but you can use a workflow set to evaluate different strategies.